# Why does this proto/phoenix toy example crash?

Tags: c++, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

I am experimenting with proto and phoenix and what is one of my first toy examples crash and I have no idea where I should be looking at. Since someone on the #boost IRC channel told me to ensure that the phoenix expression tree is first deep copied (so that there are no dangling references left when `x` has been constructed), I wrapped the expression by `boost::proto::deep_copy`. However [that didn't quite work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Rdg5D%240). It still crashes when compiled with the `-O2` flag, and [works fine when omitting it](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3IkaIU%241).

```
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/deep_copy.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bpr = boost::proto;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   using namespace boost::phoenix;
   using namespace placeholders;

   auto x = bpr::deep_copy(
   switch_(arg1)[
      case_<1>(std::cout << val("hello")),
      case_<2>(std::cout << val("bye")),
      default_(std::cout << val("default"))
   ]);

   x(1);
   x(2);
}
```

I expect this to output `hellobye`.

Comment: @llonesmiz see http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Rdg5D$0 . there is no output .

Comment: Since then, liveworkspace has update boost to version 1.53, now your code works as expected. I believe the problem was solved in 1.52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a known [bug in Phoenix](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7356). I would avoid using `phoenix::switch_` until this is sorted. Unfortunately, the maintainer of Phoenix seems to be busy with other things these days. :-(